# Would it be possible to merge my two accounts?

Tags: support, merge-accounts

For some reason, I have two accounts on Math Stackexchange. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1055/max-muller) is the old one and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/53283/max-muller?tab=profile) is the one I'm currently using. On the old one I have a fair amount of reputation points. I'd like to be able to use those for bounties.

Would it be possible to merge my two accounts in such a way that the reputation points of both accounts are added and I can log in via the e-mail address and the password of the current account is preserved?